# Joomla 3 - Add image to page

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

[image]

I would like to add different images to different pages. For example, there exists a menubar with items

- Home
- About
- Contact

and three different images

- image1.jpg
- image2.jpg
- image3.jpg

Now I would like to add image1 and image2 to "Home", image2 and image3 to "About" and image1 and image2 to "Contact".
The thing is that there is a standard banner-module in Joomla, but I have to create three different banner modules; one banner module for each page. And I would like to have one module and assign the images directly to the different pages. For example, I want an option where I can tick that image1 should be assigned to "Home" and "Contact". That would be ideal.

Is that somehow possible? I've searched the net but couldn't find any suitable solution.

Thanks,

enne

EDIT: I added one page where I want to achieve this. On the right side, there is some kind of bar and there are images which are arranged one below the other. The number and kind of images should be freely chosen by the user in the backend depending on the page.

Comment: Have you tried uing the edior to insert images on each of those pages?

This is not a programming question, so you might want to discuss on another one of the sites or read the Joomla webmaster beginner documentation.

Comment: Thanks Elin for your reply. No the images should no be inserted by editor but by some kind of module. I have added an image so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right Yes, you will have to edit the banner module which is not acceptable because it a core module. What I would suggest you to do is take a copy of it and install it as a new module. Please be sure to make the changes before you install it as a new module.

What you have to do with the Joomla module is depending on the selected menu show the picture.  If you search on google you can get more info on how to get the selected menu item in Joomla. It's really easy. You don't have to go with multiple modules.

Comment: Thanks Dasun but since I'm very new to Joomla, I would very appreciate if you would be a bit more precise. I've added an image to my original post, maybe the answer is then easier to find.